# Is it possible to create entirely new schema on every case?

Tags: spring, dbunit, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

Is there a way to create entirely new schema on every case? 
Using @DatabaseTearDown annotation is not the case here because i need to reset 
id generators as some of my test expectation rely on them (maybe it's a bad practice)

Update on rearrange my tests:

In one of my expected datasets i have:

```
<field oid="1" type="enumerated" name="simple enum field"
     dict_oid="1" required="0"
     level="1"/>

<field_enum_element field_oid="1"></field_enum_element>
<field_enum_element field_oid="1"></field_enum_element>
<field_enum_element field_oid="1"></field_enum_element>
```

where oid in term table is the generated id. I want to be sure that there are 3 rows were created in field_enum_element table but if i omit generated ids from expected data set as follows:

```
<field type="enumerated" name="simple enum field"
     dict_oid="1" required="0"
     level="1"/>

<field_enum_element></field_enum_element>
<field_enum_element></field_enum_element>
<field_enum_element></field_enum_element>
```

spring-test-db-unit thinks that there are 0 rows in the table

UPDATE:

```
  @Test
  @DatabaseSetup(value = "fieldServiceImplTest/testCreateEnumField.xml")
  @ExpectedDatabase(value = "fieldServiceImplTest/testCreateEnumField.expected.xml",
      assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT)
  @DatabaseTearDown(value = "fieldServiceImplTest/clear.xml", type = DELETE_ALL)
  public void testCreateEnumField() {
    FieldDTO fieldDTO = new FieldDTO();
    fieldDTO.setName("simple enum field");
    fieldDTO.setType("enumerated");
    fieldDTO.setLevel("term");
    fieldDTO.setIsValueRequired(false);
    fieldDTO.setDictionaryId(dictionaryService.findByOid(1L).get().returnIdentity());

    List<ItemDTO> itemDTOs = Arrays.asList(new ItemDTO(null, "complete"), new ItemDTO(null, "draft"), new ItemDTO(null, "deleted"));
    fieldDTO.setItems(new HashSet<>(itemDTOs));

    fieldService.createField(fieldDTO);
  }
```

testCreateEnumField.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
  <dictionary changed="2014-01-31 18:11:54" oid="1" client_oid="1" descr="descr" name="dictionary"/>

</dataset>
```

testCreateEnumField.expected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset reset_sequences="hibernate_sequence">
  <dictionary changed="2014-01-31 18:11:54" oid="1" client_oid="1" descr="descr" name="dictionary"/>
  <field client_oid="1" oid="1" type="enumerated" name="simple enum field"
         dict_oid="1" required="0"
         level="1"></field>

  <enum_element oid="11" client_oid="1" value="deleted"></enum_element>
  <enum_element oid="12" client_oid="1" value="draft"></enum_element>
  <enum_element oid="13" client_oid="1" value="complete"></enum_element>

  <field_enum_element field_oid="1"></field_enum_element>
  <field_enum_element field_oid="1"></field_enum_element>
  <field_enum_element field_oid="1"></field_enum_element>

</dataset>
```

Ideally i would like to be able to drop sequence between tests and test cases.

Comment: Instead of creating a new schema on each test, could you update your tests to make them independent of the id generator start value ?

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: Can you post an example of what your test looks like? Also do you need to create the schema before each test, or before each test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't exactly know what your use case is, it sounds like it's a good fit for trying the new declarative SQL feature in Spring 4.1 RC1. [Here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7655) is the JIRA issue that describes what this new feature.

Your code would look something like:

```
@Test
@Sql("fix-sequence.sql")
public void test() {
   //whatever
}
```

You can find the Javadoc of @Sql [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html).

Inside `fix-sequence.sql` you would provide the SQL needed for resetting the db for the tests

Comment: Thanks, i probably will use this feature when 4.1 Release will arrive. As for now i think i'll get by using injection of @PersistenceContext into my tests and executing drop sequence query from it.

Comment: @stanislav.chetvertkov Your welcome! I would suggest that you give the feature a try since Spring 4.1 is in RC1, and when the Release is available you can actually migrate your tests to it. It seems like the feature will save you a lot of ceremony code.

Comment: although it solves the problem it is still a workaround. Ideally i want to give dbunit a hint on number of rows in the result set.

Comment: I see your point. I haven't used dbunit before, so I can't give you any pointers in that direction

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage the problem by doing a little workaround by dropping sequence table in  @Before method with simple native sql query: "drop table hibernate_sequence".

Actually, the better solution is just to include `<hibernate_sequence next_val="1"/>` into test dataset at @DatabaseSetup phase